How can I find the maximum distance between two plots with different numbers of points in Python?
I have plotted two curves A and B (each with different number of data) extracted from a simulation with different numbers of elements and I want to extract the maximum relative error between the two (the maximum difference between the two at a same certain x-value that I don't know divided by the value at curve B).
How can I do on Python that given that they have different sizes, for example let's say curve A is plotted based on 20 data while B is based on 30 data?
I thought of choosing the one with the lowest number of data somehow using that, but I don't know if it's correct

How smooth are the curves judging by eye? If they are fairly smooth then using splines (other methods are available) to interpolate y values on the respective curves at any value of x is one way to proceed. Only you know what you actually want to do. More fundamentally it would make sense to run your simulations at the same x-values.

Not really smooth

Can you provide an example for clarity?

The curves I'm interested in are the blue one on top and the yellow one in the bottom : https://ibb.co/54cD0hq

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Anything between your points is interpolated, or you have a function which describes your plot.
Evaluate both of those plots on all the points and then calculate error between them. If you have 20 and 30 different data points, you should just get two plots with 50 points.
At least that's my idea for this.

But I can't make any operation on them if they don't have the same number of elements, I thought of just substracting one from the other and compare with my difference target value as a horizontal line but it won't work

From your picture, you can use any method to interpolate values between your points. Like @martin-brown suggested.
Or rather. You have to interpolate them. You are comparing values of some functions on different points.

What can I use? I thought of this, would it work?

Find the length of the shortest curve
min_length = min(len(curve_A), len(curve_B))
Calculate the absolute difference between the two curves up to the length of the shortest curve
abs_diff = np.abs(np.array(curve_A[:min_length]) - np.array(curve_B[:min_length]))
Find the maximum absolute difference
max_abs_diff = np.max(abs_diff)
Calculate the maximum relative error
max_rel_error = max_abs_diff / curve_B[max_abs_diff_index]

You can even assume that those curves are linear between those points and calculate new points as weighed average between beginning and end of given interval. Generally, check out what splines are.

How do I do that? I don't have a clear idea how to write it

You can check scipy tutorial https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/1D.html#tutorial-interpolate-1dsection
If you can provide some minimum working code example, it would be easier to show it.

From the documentation of numpy you can read about interp function. If you have two arrays A (short one) and B (long one) that are function of some common parameter t and you want to subtract them, first interpolate the first one to have same length as the long array.
Edit
Forgot to mention that the position for which distance is minimum is when the interpolated A-B is the lowest (in absolute value).
import numpy as np

xA = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)
A = 0.5*xA

t  = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
B = np.cos(t)

A_interp = np.interp(t, xA, A)


plt.plot(xA, A, 'o',color='C1',label='A')
plt.plot(t, B, 'o',color='C0',label='B')
plt.plot(t, A_interp, '+',color='C5',label='A_interp')
plt.plot(t,A_interp - B, ':x',color='C2',label='A_interp - B')

plt.legend()

plt.show()



